# Greyhound bus arrives very late, do I have any recourse?

Tags: buses, delays, compensation, greyhound

I know from the website that greyhound just say that they don't guarantee the time of their bus and though luck if it happens:

> The bus was late. Am I entitled to a refund?
>
> No. While Greyhound makes every effort to provide on-time service, it
>   does not guarantee its departure and arrival times, which may be
>   affected by any number of factors including weather, traffic, or
>   mechanical problems. Greyhound is not liable for any inconvenience or
>   expense caused as a result of such a delay.

From their website.

I'm in a situation where they left me stranded in Toronto in the middle of the night and I'll miss the reason I'm travelling if I continue with the bus. Hence I'm going to take another mean of transportation. I've missed two connections along the way already and I feel like dropping people in the street at 1am should be illegal. However, I'm wondering if I do have any sort of recourse in this situation or if the fact that they say on their website that they won't assume any responsibility is enough for it to be true.

Comment: Similar [previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111569/remedies-when-bus-company-makes-me-miss-a-flight)

Comment: Do you have travel insurance?

Comment: "I feel like dropping people in the street at 1am should be illegal" Um. Why? And what alternative do you propose? Should they stop the bus and keep you on it until morning? Or throw you off in the middle of nowhere after driving for another six hours?

Answer (score 4):

Just like with airlines you agreed to a [Contract of Carriage](https://www.greyhound.ca/en/ticketsandtravel/TermsAndConditions.aspx) when you purchased your ticket with Greyhound including these phrases making clear what you are buying:

> Carrier is not responsible for delays caused by breakdowns, road conditions, weather or other conditions beyond carrier’s reasonable control. [...]
>
> In no event shall carrier be liable for consequential or incidental damages for loss, damage or delay, including weather delays.

There are no legal "passenger rights" protections for delays in Canada (for planes, buses or trains) like there are in the EU, so you don't have recourse through those either.

That leaves requesting whatever compensation you see fit as a good will gesture from Greyhound (and/or the company you purchased through if you didn't buy directly).

If you purchased travel insurance (or have it through your credit card) this may provide some compensation.

Comment: While it is true that there are no passenger rights in Canada right now, this will not be true in literally 3 days time: https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/passenger-bill-of-rights-details-1.5147589

Comment: @DJClayworth interesting, only for airlines and delays protection starts end of the year.